# My app disappeared from "Background App Refresh" setting on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, background-application

My app using iBeacon and GeoFence Services worked well in the background on iOS 7.1, but it didn’t on iOS 8.
So when I went to "Background App Refresh" setting to check my app, I realized it wasn't shown in the list. I think that's y can't enable the background services.
Do I have to update my app to be compatible for iOS 8 about this point? or is it just a iOS8 bug?? Anyone, please let me know.

Comment: Have you updated your app to use the new location permissions API stuff, namely `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`?

Comment: I didn't know the new API...I'm gonna try it.Thx:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the solution!
In project target settings, go to Capabilities (second tab), in Background modes (which should be ON) there's a mode called Background Fetch.
If you check this mode, the app will appear in the Background Refresh list in phone settings.
In iOS 7 the app was in the Background Refresh list if just "Location Services" background capability was checked, but it seems that it's not enough for iOS 8.
Checking the "Background Fetch" (with or without "Location Services" capability) will fix this issue.
Edit

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer. I recently found the same solution as you :)
Btw, at the first time I was not sure so that I checked the modes “Location Services” and “Acts as a Bluetooth LE Accessory”,too, but my app was rejected by Apple. Seems like Checking only “Background fetch” was enough for my app. If you are going to make an app using iBeacon and geo-fence services, you can make sure it contains all necessary background functionality:)